# Starting from which integer is it better to switch to another product brand versioning scheme (year-based, codenames, ...)?

Tags: versioning, branding

Take a few examples:

- DirectX 11
- Silverlight 4
- OpenGL 4
- Firefox 3

I find that it is a little bit silly to have such high product version numbers: What it will mean when they'll reach version number 20? Products are just evolutions from one version to another, and the psychological impact is inversely proportional to the number magnitude (version 10.0 vs 11.0 compared to version 2.0 vs 3.0).

Common alternatives are:

- switch to a year-based scheme (Visual Studio 6 => Studio 2005, 2008, 2010)
- use abbreviation to reset the counter (Adobe CS 2,3,4..)
- use codename (Windows XP, Windows Vista)
- use hybrid codename/numbering puns (Windows Seven, MacOS X). Really clever.
- use sub-release numbers (CATIA V5 R18, R19, ...). The best thing to do IMHO.
- or even complete product re-branding.

So, starting from which number things are getting counter-productive: 3? 4? 6? 10?

Side question 1: what is the highest public version number you know of?

Side question 2: other interesting versioning alternatives to the one I suggested?

Comment: What is the market for your product?  Different market segments react very differently to the different schemes you describe.

Comment: it all depends on how you want to brand your product, and planned evolution path.

Answer (score 4):

As ever, the answer is 42.

EDIT: Oh, alright, I admit that sometimes the answer to questions on SO is 'Emacs'.

Comment: Btw, Emacs is at version 23! "Emacs 2010" could be better (and even competes with Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: @Gabriel, your comment makes a category error -- what you suggest is akin to renaming FC Barcelona so that they can compete with LA Galaxy.  Same game perhaps, but different leagues :-)

Answer (score 1):

One scheme is Ubuntu's:  an autoincremented alliterative adjective and animal.  For example, we're just getting off "Karmic Koala", and the next big thing will be (darn, can't remember, let's just go with "Leprous Lemur"), and then something like "Malevolent Macaque".  Yes, it's easy to make fun of, and the earlier versions weren't alphabetical, but incrementing the letter is probably, for reasons you mentioned, better than incrementing a number.  Of course, there's room for speculation for what comes after "Zymurgic Zebra", as there are no adjectives or animal names beginning with "[" or "{" (depending on whether you're looking at uppercase ASCII/Unicode characters or lowercase).

Edit:  Also X may be a problem.  Xanthippic Xerophyte?

Comment: It's another scheme, but it's a notably bad one.  For one, the names are hard to remember.  Secondly, since each release has a number name based on the release date, there are two possible ways to refer to it.  If someone only mentions "Lucid Lynx" in their post (and manages to get it spelled right), but you are searching for 10.04, you probably won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's really rather simple:

**Option 1:** you rename it every time
**Reason 1:** Marketing Department are weak and/or outsourced

**Option 2:** you increment the numeral
**Reason 2:** Marketing Department can, will, and has at least once already kicked Software Department's ass

Rebranding is a nightmare. Seriously, you guys.